# Discrete gradient on point clouds

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, discrete-geometry

I am interested to know some ways to approximate discrete gradient if you have a function on point clouds in 2D or 3D.

If you have a function defined on a grid, it well known that you can use a standard difference formula to compute the partial derivative in each direction.

I came across [a paper](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~yusu/papers/sgp2009.pdf) by Luo et al entitled Approximating Gradients for Meshes and Point Clouds via Diffusion Metric which uses diffusion metric. Another idea that came into mind is to defined a smoothed field using a specific kernel, then to take the gradient of the smoothed function.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Very many numerical methods for partial differential equations compute derivatives from values on something that is not a regular grid (they use *unstructured grids*).  Usually these are finite element methods and they use more than just point values (they have various local integrals of the function available).

A class of methods based on what you're asking for are the so-called [meshfree methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meshfree_methods).  Typically, they use the point values to generate a continuous approximation by convolving with some smooth kernel (e.g., a Gaussian).  Then they compute derivatives of the continuous function.  Of course, if you have a lot of points this becomes expensive and there are lots of additional tricks you can play (e.g., using a kernel with compact support; employing the *fast multipole method*, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, there is not a standard method - and be aware that the calculation will be sensitive to noise.

A straightforward of calculating the gradient would be: Take some point $x$ and choose a numbers of neigbors (the nearest $k$, say). Now fit a hyperplane through the $k+1$ points (e.g. by a least squares fit) and take the slope of this plane as the gradient in $x$.